# Denominators in Convergents of Continued Fraction

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\theta, \theta'$ be the roots of the equation $x^2-ax-1=0$, where $a$ is a positive integer and $\theta >0$. Show that the denominators in the convergents to $\theta$ are given by $q_{n-1}=(\theta^n-\theta'^{n})/(\theta-\theta')$. Verify that the Fibonacci sequence 1, 1, 2, 3, 5,... is given by $q_0, q_1,...$ in a special case.

Comment: The positive solution of $x^2-ax-1$ is $$u=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4}+a}{2}$$ and $u$ satisfies $\frac{1}{u}=u-a$. So, the continued fraction of $u$ is $[a,a,a,a\cdots ]$ Take it from here.

Comment: Can you please give me more hints? I also don't understand how you got to that continued fraction. Do I need to work backwards somehow? I know how to go from a continued fraction to its quadratic irrational, but not the other way around

Comment: The crucial idea is that subtracting the first entry and taking the reciprocal gives the number we have if the first entry is removed. In the case of $[a,a,a,a,\cdots]$ however, we get the same number. Therefore the equation. I did not calculate the final expression of $q_{n-1}$, but induction should be a good idea as in the related question.